# How do I delay spacebar when I type?

Tags: keyboard, typing

When I type i inevitably hit the space bar before I have finished a word. Let me **giv eyou** an example. See?

Any tips on how to avoid this? Spacebar delay software, mechanical devices? I have tried to alter my typing but 40 years of bad habits are hard to shake.

EDIT: using Dragon Naturally Speaking avoids the problem, but I cannot use it all the time.

Comment: The example is "giv eyou" in the text.

Comment: Spellchecker, autocorrect, or the like? That might also convert "When I type i" into "When I type, I". (And I suffer from essentially the same porblem)

Comment: Do yo umean "por blem" ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity: how come you have developed this habit? I guess if it generated the problem from the very beginning, then you wouldn't have developed it. So supposably there was a device that delayed the space bar. What was it? Some mechanical typewriter maybe?

Comment: Nothing special, just my thumb seems to hit it before my fingers are ready. Just did it then!